# ASP.NET/C# - URL Rewriting or Shortening URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

Consider the following URL:

```
http://localhost:1234/Websites/Shop/ProductDetails.aspx/1234/Beauty-Cup
```

What is the best way to shorten the url and would still give me the same result?

```
http://localhost:1234/Products/1234/Beauty-Cup
```

> 1234 - Is a product code (this is where I retrieve the product's details)
>
> Beauty-Cup - Is the products name (just for display purposes)

Basically, in the original path, I use `Request.PathInfo` to do my necessary checking and validation on the product code. This function is located in `Page_Load` of `ProductDetails.aspx`

Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lots of resources out there on this. See here for example. https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net

Comment: P.S. This would have been a lot easier using MVC for ASP.NET. Did you look at this as a possible option? Is it a new development ?

Comment: I learned to use `Request.PathInfo` from there, else the the original URL would be `?productCode=1234&productName=Beauty-Cup`. Trust me, I've tried most, but none of them seemed to work

Comment: Also, here. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RedirectingASPNETLegacyURLsToExtensionlessWithTheIISRewriteModule.aspx